# mongodb - get highest value of a sum groupped by a field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i suppose we have this data

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 2, "category" : 1}

{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "quantity" : 1, "category" : 1}

{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5, "category" : 2}

{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 10, "category" : 2}

{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10, "category" : 3}

{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "cds", "quantity" : 9, "category" : 3}
```

i want to make a query that give me the category that contain the biggest quantity.
so i have to:

1- group by category

2- make the sum of quantities of items in each category

3- get the highest value among those sums.

Please help me to make this query.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like an assignment question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$sort` with `$limit` to get the maximum total:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  { $group: {
         _id: '$category',
         sumQ: {$sum: '$quantity'}
      } 
  },
  { $sort: {sumQ: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```