# Symfony - Mongodb - sum and group by

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I suppose we have this data

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 2, "category" : 1}

{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "quantity" : 1, "category" : 1}

{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5, "category" : 2}

{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 10, "category" : 2}

{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10, "category" : 3}

{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "cds", "quantity" : 9, "category" : 3}
```

I want to make a query that give me the category that contain the biggest quantity. so I have to:

1- Group by category

2- Make the sum of quantities of items in each category

3- Get the highest value among those sums.

So in Mongodb I got a little help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712507/mongodb-get-highest-value-of-a-sum-groupped-by-a-field) :

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  { $group: {
         _id: '$category',
         sumQ: {$sum: '$quantity'}
      } 
  },
  { $sort: {sumQ: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

But when I want to convert that with the
`createAggregationBuilder`
I couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who search the same proble i found the solution :

```
$builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder(Production::class);
$builder
    ->match()
        // put what you want here
    ->group()
        ->field('id')            
        ->expression('$category')
        ->field('quantity')
        ->sum('$quantity')
    ->sort(['quantity' => -1])
    ->limit(1)
```

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: How to get result out of this aggregation builder query? Tried "->execute" but it isn't showing the expected result.